# Not Showing Correct Form Label

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm having a hard time debugging to locate the issue here.
I've tried echoing `$login_by_username` and `$login_by_email` but they aren't echoing.

The problem is when it loads the login form it always puts email as the label.

Controller:

```
$login_by_username = $this->config->item('login_by_username', 'config1');
$login_by_email = $this->config->item('login_by_email', 'config1');
$this->data['login_by_username'] = $login_by_username;
$this->data['login_by_email'] = $login_by_email;
```

View:

```
<?php
if ($login_by_username AND $login_by_email) 
{
    $login_label = 'Email or Username';
} 
else if ($login_by_username) 
{
    $login_label = 'Username';
} 
else 
{
    $login_label = 'Email';
}
?>
<?php echo form_label($login_label, 'login'); ?>
```

Config:

```
$config['login_by_username'] = TRUE;
$config['login_by_email'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending you data from your controller to the view?

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to load the view? Are you passing `$this->data` in the second parameter?

Comment: @Daniel yes becasuse my other variables work

Comment: just check them before sending to your view

Comment: how do I check them if they are bool

Comment: I did that but for some reason it always returns FALSE. I updated my question to include config setting.

Comment: make sure that your `config1.php` have those values in it

Comment: I am I showed the config1 values above.

Comment: try using those variables on the default config file and call them like this: `$login_by_username = $this->config->item('some_key')`

Comment: also make sure your `config1.php` is inside the `config` folder

Comment: it is inside that folder

Comment: have you tried using the default config file instead of yours?

Comment: When NI move them to the default config file it returns TRUE correctly now what is happening to prevent me from using a second config file.

Comment: ok...are you loading your config file on your controller? `$this->config->load('config1');` ?

Comment: I've autoloaded it as autoload['config'] = array('config1');

Comment: try loading it on your controller instead

Comment: That works too so now I'm just at this point curious to know why its not autoloading the config file I have in the array.

Comment: I'm gonna check here on my computer and report back in a minute

Comment: I made a test and it worked as expected. I'm gonna answer your question with details

Comment: @user1406861 answered, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our comments.

You have used the `autoload.php` to call your config file.

You made some tests to make sure that the problem is with your `config1.php` file and not with `CI`.

I've made a test and here is what I did.

I have created a file `config1.php` inside: `application/config`.

Here it is:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config['teste'] = 'config1 test';
```

On my `autoload.php` also inside `application/config`:

`$autoload['config'] = array('config1');`

My Home Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array('config'=>$this->config->item('teste'));
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

My view:

```
<?php echo $config;?>
```

And `config1 test` is echoed as expected.

Comment: how can I do it so that I can echo the itemnot the array key

Comment: I don't get what you want...don't you want to access a value from a config file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that config items `login_by_username` and `login_by_email` are there in the `config1.php` file
2. Make sure that you are passing `$this->data` while loading the view eg:

   $this->load->view('view.php', $this->data)

Comment: If you look at the comments above I have already mentioned these.

Comment: I did because I had said that my other variables work that are getting passed.

Comment: Try after assigning the values directly for $login_by_username and for $login_by_email instead of loading it from config file.

Comment: @Habeeb that will totally make the config files useless. The best option if to find the problem for that error and not some workarounds, IMO

Comment: @Daniel - That's just for a testing to find out the real issue. If it's working without the config file, then it's an issue with config file and concentrate on that.